# Selectize JS plugin installing plugins via Node JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, laravel

I have installed the Selectize Javascript plugin to my site via NPM. I then copy this file into a public facing directory using gulp.

My problem now is including a plugin file. From within my public asset directory I have the following structure /src/plugins/selectable_placeholder which is as per the structure required in the selectize instructions
https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/plugins.md

However including, or not including the JS file leads to an error where either
`Uncaught Error: Unable to find "selectable_placeholder" plugin`

Or

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Selectize is not defined`

Both are caused by the file either not being picked up, or if finds the file and then cannot find the Selectize object.

I can see why this is happening, but now how to fix it, other than by hacking the core selectize code which defeats the point in the plugin features..

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Have you found out how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It might be due the file permission is not adequate . Cross check the file permission, is having full access

use if you are in ubundu  `sudo chmod 777 [path of file]`

If you are  windows change the file permission from properties

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I never did work out the issue but thanks anyway.